# Logitech M310 doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: usb, mouse, logitech

My wireless mouse, the Logitech M310, and the bundled keyboard, Logitech K520, don't work on my laptop. When switching to Windows 7, they work out-of-the-box just fine. The internets say this mouse should work just fine on Ubuntu too. What's wrong here?

I'm on a Asus Zenbook UX32VD, running Ubuntu 12.10 (64bit).

lsusb does list the receiver:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b330 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp.
```

dmesg | grep Logitech:

```
[    2.566231] usb 3-3: >Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.574566] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: >hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input2
[  208.590420] usb 3-2: >Manufacturer: Logitech
[  208.610791] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input11
[  208.611166] hid-generic 0003:046D:C521.0004: >input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[  208.613884] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/input/input12
[  208.614523] hid-generic 0003:046D:C521.0005: >input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
```